# asp.net C# how to programmatically change body background-image on Page_Load

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, css, image

I'm trying to make simple webpage here is my body in HTML code

```
  <body runat="server" id="BodyTag" style="height: 1171px; width: 1148px;">
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
```

On Page_Load in my Form.aspx.cs file i want to generate random number from 1 to X
where X is the number of files in a specific folder(folder containing images) then i want the body background image to be this random generated number as long as the image names in the folder are 1,2, ... , ... Here is my code

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string path = "C:/Users/FluksikartoN/documents/visual studio 2012/Projects/FLUKSIKARTON/FLUKSIKARTON/WebPhotos/BackGroundPhotos";
            int countF = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Length;
           Random rand = new Random((int)DateTime.Now.Ticks);
            int n = rand.Next(1, countF);
            BodyTag.Style["background-image"] = "C:/Users/FluksikartoN/documents/visual studio 2012/Projects/FLUKSIKARTON/FLUKSIKARTON/WebPhotos/BackGroundPhotos/" + n.ToString() + ".jpg";



        }
```

body background image does not change, it stays white and i dont understand why.Please do not hesitate to ask more information if you need

Comment: Don't use a local filesystem path for your image location.

Answer (score 2):

This is better achieved with css. Since you need a way to do it from code, the easiest option that comes to my mind is do it with generated Javascript

**Javascript**

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
     document.body.style.background = "url('http://localhost:53942/images/_65209699_fanbase_bbc.jpg')";
     document.body.style.backgroundRepeat = 'no-repeat';
 </script>
```

**Applying it to your code**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string script = "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
             document.body.style.background = \"url('http://localhost:53942/images/_65209699_fanbase_bbc.jpg')";
             document.body.style.backgroundRepeat = 'no-repeat';
         </script>\";

    ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "background-changer-script", script);
}
```

This will just spill the Javascript to the bottom of your page and will be executed by the browser, changing the background as expected. Check the intellisense for Javascript and CSS for other background properties that can be set

Answer (score 0):

You likely need to use a web relative URL:

```
BodyTag.Style["background-image"] = "http://localhost/FLUKSIKARTON/WebPhotos/BackGroundPhotos/" + n.ToString() + ".jpg";
```

Another approach would be to provide 1 CSS class per image and then switch which is being used:

CSS

```
.image1 {
    background-image: url('/FLUKSIKARTON/WebPhotos/BackGroundPhotos/1.jpeg');
}
```

C#

```
BodyTag.CssClass = string.Format("image{0}.jpeg", n);
```

Comment: BodyTag.Style["background-image"] = "http://localhost/FLUKSIKARTON/WebPhotos/BackGroundPhotos/" + n.ToString() + ".jpg";

still does not work

Comment: Check that the URL you're rendering to the browser is the correct URL - copy it and paste it in your browser URL bar and check that the image is shown

Comment: well when i copy the Image Path and place it in my browser this is what appears :

file:///C:/Users/FluksikartoN/Documents/Visual%20Studio%202012/Projects/FLUKSIKARTON/FLUKSIKARTON/WebPhotos/BackGroundPhotos/1.jpg

Comment: You need to render a web accessible URL to the browser; this is not web accessible

Comment: Try this: BodyTag.Style["background-image"] = "/WebPhotos/BackGroundPhotos/" + n.ToString() + ".jpg";

Comment: WTF nice it worked but because of resolution the image appears many times how can i correct this so one image is displayed

Comment: i mean my body is big so it places as much images as it can to fill the body if i correct the body size it  will remove the problem but what about a code that makes the whole body one image

Comment: Sounds like a new question :-)

Comment: Yea :) something like this