# Changing Aspx Page Body Image on PageLoad - ASP.Net

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, css

I have a site I am putting together in Asp.Net, and have run into an issue where I would like one of my pages to load a "different image" for the page's background. The original image, which is also used throughout most of the site, sits in a CSS script file:

```
body   
{
   background-image: url('../Images/SkyBackMain.jpg');
}
```

However, on the page where I would like to change the image, I've placed javascript in the code behind for the load event, but I'm getting several errors. Here is the code behind w/ the code:

```
public partial class TechCall : System.Web.UI.Page
{
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string script = "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
        document.body.style.background = \"url('../Images/CPUBack_2nd.jpg')";
        document.body.style.backgroundRepeat = 'no-repeat';
    </script>\";

    ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "background-changer-script", script);
}
}
```

I get the errors as follows:

1. `"<script type=\"text/javascript\">` -- Newline in constant error.
2. `\"url('../Images/CPUBack_2nd.jpg')";` -- Invalid expression term and ;expected.
3. `'no-repeat';` -- Too many characters in character literal.
4. `</script>\";` -- Error: Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement.

When researching this question on a similar post, I applied the Javascript concept, yet I get these errors.  Am I missing something here, whereas I need to place Javascript elsewhere prior to the code-behind page? I'm at a loss on where else it needs to be if so. Your insight is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is it a must to do it this way, why simply just write the script in this specific page, also try to use Jquery it is very simple job to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you forget to do a proper concatenation

```
 string script = "<script type=\"text/javascript\">"
                            + "document.body.style.background = \"url('../Images/CPUBack_2nd.jpg')"
                            + "document.body.style.backgroundRepeat = 'no-repeat';"
                            + "</script>\"";
```

***EDIT***
here is a better way to do it (less confusing)

```
StringBuilder script = new StringBuilder();
script.Append("<script type=\"text/javascript\">");
script.Append("document.body.style.background = \"url('../Images/CPUBack_2nd.jpg')\";");
script.Append("document.body.style.backgroundRepeat = 'no-repeat';");
script.Append("</script>");
this.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "changeBackground", script.ToString());
```

please read more about how to register a client side script from the server-side

[RegisterClientScriptBlock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/btf44dc9%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: by the way I didn't try what have you did in that javascript code

Comment: This does not work at all; why would I need to make this a String...? It isn't input, it's actual code that needs to function.

Comment: I think you need to read more about RegisterClientScriptBlock http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/btf44dc9%28v=vs.110%29.aspx
you pass the javascript code as an string argument, that's why you need to concatenate all the javascript as a string before you can use it in your load method

Comment: Ok, I will try this. However, I've also got this piece of Javascript and wonder does this need to go anyway in the Master Page or some other place, in addition to what you've suggested:

`<script type="text/javascript">
    document.body.style.background = "url('../Images/CPUBack_2nd.jpg')";
    document.body.style.backgroundRepeat = 'no-repeat';
  </script>
`

Comment: please try my answer and let me know if it works, you can add this script in the page that you want to change it's background

Comment: Lastly, I am not getting the highlight on StringBuilder or the Append keywords... is it this goes in my code-behind in the Page_Load event handler? It's telling he namespace StringBuilder could not be found.

Comment: No... your example is not working. Everywhere I place this my program is blowing up with errors. Some specific placement on what goes where is needed. Please remember that my pages are based off a Master page, and the page I want the change in is Aspx child page of the Master page - so it has no HTML markup, just <asp:Content> tags. Thank you.

Comment: you need to add using System.Text; at the beginning of the page please try to read more about C# and .net this is very basic statement that you can't be missing

Comment: Your example fits and I get no errors, but for some reason the image I want is not pulling from the Images folder. The code doesn't blow up, but nothing happens, it shows the same image which is delegated to it. I cannot for the life of me wrap my head around this issue.  Have a look at this post and see if you can garner any input from it:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20554669/asp-net-c-sharp-how-to-programmatically-change-body-background-image-on-page-loa

Comment: I told you I didn't test whatever you have wrote, but I did now and I fixed some missing semicolon and double quotation, and it is working now be sure about your image location path, if this works with you should mark my answer as an accepted answer so if someone else read it,he can benefit from it, thanks

Comment: Your edit has now caused the background to simply turn "white", with no image at all showing up. If the image path is not as such: `"url('../Images/someimage.jpg');` Then what else is there? This is the path used for the default image in the CSS body rule. I am going to simply abort this question and seek out a professor who can break this down. Stack OverFlow has not been helpful in providing clear resolution to this query... there is too much ambiguity from example to example, with no clear cut step by step instruction to avoid confusion. Thank you for your efforts.

Comment: stackoverflow is not a tutorial website or an absolute beginner guide simply you asked a question and you got the answer but you are the one who can't apply it, I have applied the answer by copying and pasting it without further editing and it works like charm I just added directory with the image and nothing else!! oh my god what a waste of time!!!!!

Comment: I have made the directory hierarchy based upon your original post in the question Images folder at the root level and an image with the same name you have supplied in this folder!!, simply I tried to mimic your environment so you don't need to change any thing in your hierarchy just copy and paste your code after fixing in my solution on the load event and no errors, no faults or no missing images.

Comment: By the way If you can't find my answer helpful enough for you, no problem simply leave it and wait for someone else to give you the answer you desire thanks.

Comment: Thank you for getting me there with you knowledge of Javascript to help solve the problem. I eventually figured it out that the path needed to be completely Root Relative within the script's url specification.

Hence, `url('/Project/ImageFolder/ImageFile.jpg');`

That got it showing, plus I cleaned up some of Master page inline CSS and moved it to the style sheet for proper isolation. Thanks again, and no hard feelings... frustration just set in. Cheers!